# What is the meaning of flag -s in this command?

Tags: terminal, zsh, zshrc

I have met a command to load nvm environment in .zshrc, but I don't know what it exactly does with flag -s. I know that the square bracket is condition to check whether folder in this command exists or not. But don't know what -s does.

`[ -s "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm`

Does anyone know the flag -s in this command? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[` is the same as `test`. Checking `test`'s manpage:

```
-s file       True if file exists and has a size greater than zero.
```

Update: Actually, using `man '['` works, too.